# FORM vs BODY in documentation?

Tags: functions, elisp-macros, documentation, doc-strings

Recently I was trapped by `void-variable` error on `eval-after-load`.

That is not first time I forget to quote args like:

```el
(eval-after-load 'sql
   '(progn
       ...))
```

because `eval-after-load` docs say:

```el
(eval-after-load FILE FORM)
```

I wrongly expect that `FORM` is like `BODY...` for example in `when`:

```el
(when COND BODY...)
```

What is the difference between `FORM` and `BODY` function call contract?

Why are there `FORM` when `BODY` is more convenient?

`BODY` only for macros and `FORM` only for functions?

Is `(quote (progn ...))` usual way to make multi expression `FORM`?

**UPDATE** Seems my guess is right about *`BODY` only for macros and `FORM` only for functions*:

```el
(defmacro with-eval-after-load (file &rest body)
  "Execute BODY after FILE is loaded.
FILE is normally a feature name, but it can also be a file name,
in case that file does not provide any feature."
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  `(eval-after-load ,file (lambda () ,@body)))
```

Comment: eval-after-load is a poorly designed function which you shouldn't take as example for anything :)

Comment: Section [Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Forms.html#Forms) in the manual gives this definition: *a Lisp object that is intended to be evaluated is called a form (or an expression)*. Regarding bodies and macros: both function calls and macro calls may take a "list" (**not** in the Lisp sense) of forms, which is usually called a "body". You can recognize ones that can take several forms by the `&rest` keyword in the argument list. (I'm leaving this as a comment because I don't have the time to write a proper answer.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here.

On the one hand, when a function is called, the arguments are evaluated first. But when you evaluate a macro, the arguments are not evaluated. Instead, they are used to expand the macro into a form, which is subsequently evaluated.

On the other hand, a *form* is just a single lisp object that is going to be evaluated, while a *body* is a sequence of forms.

It is true that macro calls more commonly contain a body than a single form. This has less to do with their macro-ness than with what is more natural in each case, however.

The built-in function `eval` is something of a special case: It is a function, hence when you call it, its argument is evaluated. But then, it evaluates its (already evaluated) argument again. The purpose of this is so you can programmatically build a lisp form and then evaluate it. This is rarely needed in ordinarty programming, however – but it's a common beginner's error for new lispers to use `eval` needlessly.

And so at last we get to `eval-after-load`: I imagine it is a function primarily because its perceived relationship with plain `eval`. It might have been better to have it being a macro, but then the name should have been different so it's not so easily confused with the semantics of `eval`. Perhaps `run-after-load`? You can easily make one such yourself, perhaps even allowing it a body:

```
(defmacro run-after-load (file &rest body)
  `(eval-after-load ,file '(progn ,@body)))
```

**Edit:** There is in fact a macro `with-eval-after-load` in newer emacsen (since 24.4) which is almost identical to the above. (It wraps the body in a `lambda` instead of a `progn`.)

Comment: You could mention the macro `with-eval-after-load`, which was added in a fairly recent Emacs version. It is mostly equivalent to your `run-after-load`.

Comment: @Constantine Good catch! Done. Thanks.

Comment: It's new in 24.4, specifically (check NEWS: `<f1> n`).

Comment: Whoops, I had forgotten a quote! After all, `eval-after-load does evaluate its argument, right? Which is what was causing trouble for the OP. In any case, hopefully most users will have emacs 24.4 and just go with `with-eval-after-load` instead.